# Mage registry key "original_include_path" already exists

Tags: magento-1.8, database, error, fatal-error, key

I'm trying to fix the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in Abstract line 514
```

Because i cant enter my manage customers in the backend

I did a trace and it shows me this :

```
Mage registry key "original_include_path" already exists
```

Anyone knows what is going wrong here and knows a fix?

Answer (score 1):

That Mage registry error is telling you that you or Magento has already set data to the registry key `original_include_path` and that it cannot be overwritten. Magento registry must be unset and reset if you want to modify its value.

You shouldn't get this error unless you have some modifications that's not quite right. I would do a text search over your code base for "`Mage::register('original_include_path',`" and see if you get any hits in customized areas. If you don't find any unusual stuff, maybe the workflow is incorrect.

Comment: i"m new in magento. Do you got any example what i need to do?

Comment: I can fix this error, but than im at the start of the first error. The fatal one